# Is there a similar way in DART for declarative ui?

Tags: dart

Since Dart is a Browser aimed language, and it looks the demo code to build an UI are all dom based. So my question is: Can we do declarative ui style in Dart? like the GWT's UIBinder, or JavaFX's FXML?

Answer (score 1):

Declarative UI definition like in GWT's UiBinder is a wistfully awaited feature in Dart. Unfortunately there is no built-in Dart library for this purpose yet. [Google's first own templating lib approach](http://dart.googlecode.com/svn/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/utils/template/) was disposed as the last commit was on June 11. Apparently Google is investigating a completely new UI approach.

However there are 3rd party developers who provide frameworks on top of Dart that include a declarative UI definition, e.g. the [**Buckshot UI** framework](https://github.com/prujohn/Buckshot) and here's a [demo how it works](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOacOkmd9FI).

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [Buckshot](https://github.com/prujohn/Buckshot) from John Evans. It's a declarative UI for Dart.

Here's an example:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TreeView</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='BuckshotHost'></div>

    <script id='main' type='text/xml'>
        <treeview name='tvDemo' borderthickness='1' bordercolor='Black' >
            <treenode header='Tree Node L1A' >
                <treenode header='Tree Node L2A (custom icon)' >
                    <fileicon>
                        <border width='20' height='20' cornerradius='20' background='Orange' />
                    </fileicon>
                </treenode>
                <treenode header='Tree Node L2B'>
                    <treenode header='Tree Node L3A' />
                    <treenode header='Tree Node L3B' />
                    <treenode header='Tree Node L3C' />
                </treenode>
                <treenode header='Tree Node L2C' />
            </treenode>
            <treenode header='Tree Node L1B' />
        </treeview>
    </script>

    <script type="application/dart" src="TreeViewDemo.dart"></script>
    <script src="dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```